# в андроид приложении как сделать так чтобы google карта каждые 5 секунд обновилось

Tags: java, android

у меня в приложении на Google карте  маркеры видны в радиусе 100 метров как сделать так чтобы когда я передвигался карта автоматически обновлялась и показала маркеры,я пишу код на java или сделать так что бы карта каждые 5 секунд обновилась.помогите

Answer (score 0):

С карты вы всегда можете получить свое местоположение через callback `googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener`. Через Location сервис можно задать время обновления местоположения

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
```

И после каждого вызова callback делать запросы на сервер с вашим положением и радиусом

Comment: можете здесь показать пример кода ?